# unwanted dialog appears when pressing enter key

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

I am developing an online radio project. In the middle of hearing music, if the user presses the enter key, sometimes a dialog is displayed.  What is the remedy for this?

Comment: what kind of dialog, any text is mentioned on it or the clock dialog appears??

Comment: A dialog Box "Changes Made" and three buttons Save,Discard,Cancel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
protected void onSavePrompt()
{
   return true;
}

 protected void onClose()
    {
       return true;
    }
```

add the code in ur screen where the issue arises.
One method is for closing and one for saving.

depending on your requirement u can add both or any
Hope this helps.